# Javascript Array Copy getting corrupted

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, deep-copy

I have an array of objects in React State:
this.state.expandableRowSwitches is an array of objects:

{ display: false, selected: false, ghosted: false }

When I try to make a copy of the array to manipulate it (deep or shallow), I do not get an exact copy back if I follow the copying line with a line that manipulates a particular index of the array.  If I comment that line out, the copy goes back to being perfect when executed. The only single form of copying the array that doesn't do this is JSON.parse(JSON.stringify) but I do not want to rely on that as a method. I tried everything else including lodash's deepClone and even a plain for loop. Again, when I use the JSON.parse method, my program executes as expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
onTableRowDoubleClick(index) {
    console.log('onTableRowDoubleClick');
    let arrayCopy = [];
    arrayCopy = _.cloneDeep(this.state.expandableRowSwitches);
    //let arrayCopy = _.clone(this.state.expandableRowSwitches);
    //let arrayCopy = this.state.expandableRowSwitches.splice(0);
    //let arrayCopy = [...this.state.expandableRowSwitches];
    //let arrayCopy = this.state.expandableRowSwitches.slice(0);
    arrayCopy[index].display = !arrayCopy[index].display;
    return arrayCopy;
}`
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question, but have you tried with [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/from)?

Comment: I just tried that right now and arrayCopy = Array.from(this.state.expandableRowSwitches) gives me the same exact problem.  All the switches are converted to true (they start out as false).  This has the effect of all my rows expanding when only one row should expand (by the display switch being set to true for only that single index). When I use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify...  as the copying method, everything works as expected.  I do not want to rely on that copy method though

Answer (score 0):

The objects at copied array are referencing objects at original array. You can use `Object.assign()` to set each object as a new object setting properties and values to same as original object, to break the mutual object reference.

```
let arrayCopy = this.state.expandableRowSwitches.map(o => Object.assign({}, o));
```

```js
const arr = Array({a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}); // original array

let copy = arr.slice(0); // copy of original array

arr[0].a = 5; // set `"a"` at index 0 of `arr` to `5`

console.log(copy[0].a); // `"a"` at index 0 of `copy` is also set to `5`

copy = arr.map(o => Object.assign({}, o)); // set `o` as a new object

arr[0].a = 1; // set `"a"` at index 0 of `arr` to `5`

console.log(copy[0].a); // `5`,  not set to `1` by `arr` reference
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  Although I don't understand why lodash's _.cloneDeep(this.state.expandableRowSwitches) doesn't work, since that method is supposed to return a deep copy of the array without references...

Comment: @JaredBoice Not sure about `_.cloneDeep` method of `lodash`. Does documentation provide details of return value?

Comment: it says: "Returns the deep cloned value." I see that Object.assign only performs a shallow copy (which in this case I assume works since the objects in each array element don't go another level deep?) ... what would you recommend in cases when there are multiple levels of objects within objects?  Thanks again, much appreciated

Comment: You can use iteration, recursion or scheduling to call `Object.assign()` at object which has property which references object at value.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I was doing arrayCopy = _.cloneDeep(this.state.expandableRowSwitches) when I should have been doing arrayCopy = this.state.expandableRowSwitches.map(o => _.cloneDeep(o));